# Can common mode VCC/GND transients cause false clocking in a D flip-flop?

Tags: emc, esd

I have a low complexity board with a [sn74lvc1g175 D flip-flop](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g175-ep.pdf) that occasionally gets clocked by nearby discharges with an ESD testing gun.  These are not discharges into the actual circuit, just nearby discharges.

Since the entire PCB is less than 1 square inch and the clock net is only a fraction of an inch long, my thought is that coupling into the clock is unlikely.  The PCB is (necessarily) powered by a cable that is several feet long, so that seems the more likely source of coupling for the ESD induced noise.

Can common mode transients on the VCC and GND inputs of a CMOS flip-flop cause false clocking?

Comment: Please post schematics and PCB layout?

Comment: Unfortunately, because of the proprietary nature of the design, I can't post a PCB layout.  I'm more looking for general guidance noise induced failures of FFs.

Comment: So how would we even begin to analyze this then without any info about the circuit?

Comment: As I said, I'm not asking for a circuit analysis, just the possible pulse induced failure modes of a flip flop.  In my personal opinion, in this particular case, coupling into the clock is less likely, but i don't know if false clocking by coupling into the power supply is a valid failure mode for FFs

Comment: Listing all possibilities and how to prevent them could fill a book. And there are already good books on the subject.

Comment: I'm not asking how to prevent general problems. I'm asking specifically for potential FF false clocking failure modes.

Comment: It's impossible to say if it's applicable, impossible, likely, probable or anything else in your case. This is as detailed as "Can I bend this piece of metal...but I won't tell you anything about it". Could be a paperclip, could be a tank. Voting to close for that reason until edited and substantially improved, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'd suggest a fast 'scope, x100 probe, and low-inductance ground connection. Probe the clock and power rails and *see* what is happening.  Otherwise we're just talking theoreticals.

Comment: I edited the question to hopefully satisfy the down voters.  I'm really just looking to see if anyone has had experience with common mode transients causing false clocking in a FF.

Comment: Can you post layout please?

Answer (score 2):

ESD spark events are wide bandwidth events and inject energy in the air at high frequency.

That energy can be picked up by a long PCB trace or by an external cable.

If one or more VDD traces are not stable with respect to the GND plane during ESD events, than sequential circuits like flip-flop can flip their state.

You might want to filter and decouple all VDD traces by X7R or X5R ceramic capacitors of 1 nF or below.

Another effective method is adding a resistor R in series to all the data/control lines of the EMC victim chip. R can vary from a 10 Ohm to several 100 kOhm.

You might also want to add a metal shield connected to GND, over the EMC victim chip.

Design short PCB traces.